# Making a VNC viewer for the ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, vnc

Im currently working on a app for Dynacloud, i can control VM's/datacenters/storages etc..
but now i need to make it able to go "into" a VM with a VNC connection.

All VM's already have a VNC server on it but now i just need to get from the ipad into the VM and i dont know where to start.

so could annyone tell me were to `start`?

Comment: Did you manage to find a starting vnc source code project ? I'm looking for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother writing your own. It will take you far longer and cost more than buying one.

Search the app store for VNC, there are several iPad apps that do VNC.